# QueryDSL join with limit 1

Tags: querydsl

I have two tables like this:

```
+------------------+              +------------------+                                                                                                                                 
|     CHANGESET    | 1         N  |     DECISION     |                                                                                                                                 
|                  |--------------|                  |                                                                                                                                 
|                  |              |                  |                                                                                                                                 
+------------------+              +------------------+
```

I need to get list of CHANGESET records based on some criteria and join only one DECISION record, the last one based on dateTimeStamp.

So, I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CHANGESET ch
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM
      (
        SELECT * FROM CHANGESETDECISION
        ORDER BY DECISIONTIMESTAMP DESC
      )
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ) chd
      ON chd.CHANGESETID = ch.ID
  WHERE ch.CHANGESETSTATUSID IN ('DRAFT','APPROVED')
          -- AND some other criteria...
ORDER BY ch.ID;
```

Or I can have the same result with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT
      RANK()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY CH.ID
        ORDER BY CHD.DECISIONTIMESTAMP ) rnk,
      ch.*,
      chd.DECISIONTIMESTAMP,
      chd.CHANGESETID
    FROM CHANGESET ch
      LEFT JOIN CHANGESETDECISION chd ON chd.CHANGESETID = ch.ID
  ) WHERE rnk = 1;
```

What I need is to write it in QueryDSL. I tried something like this:

```
    private SQLQuery getLastApproved() {
        return createQuery()
            .from(CHANGESETDECISION)
            .limit(1)
            .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.DESC, CHANGESETDECISION.decisiontimestamp))
            .where(CHANGESETDECISION.approved.eq(COMMON_YES_VALUE));
    }
```

and join it to:

```
createQuery()
            .from(CHANGESET)
            .leftJoin(getLastApproved())
            .where(CHANGESETDECISION.decisiontimestamp.isNull().or(CHANGESETDECISION.decisiontimestamp.eq(getTimestamp())))
            .list();
```

but it simply doesn't work because `SQLQuery` or `SQLSubQuery` are not based on `EntityPath<?>`.

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve it?

In project we are using QueryDSL 3.6.9.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to use querydsl 3.6.9**

Use the `leftJoin` method `public Q leftJoin(SubQueryExpression<?> target, Path<?> alias)`, example to follow using querydsl 3.6.9.

```
PathBuilder<String> alias = new PathBuilder<>(String.class, "alias");
query.from(dual)
        .leftJoin(new SQLSubQuery()
                .from(dual)
                .list(dual.dummy), alias)
        .on(alias.get(dual.dummy).eq(dual.dummy));
```

Comment: There is no leftJoin which takes query as the first argument and alias as the second in 3.6.9. LeftJoin takes (EntityPath target) or (RelationalFuncitionCall target, Path alias) or (SubQueryExpression target, Path alias) or (ForeignKey key, entity) only.

Comment: Updated to use querydsl 3.6.9.